# Submit Spark job through "spark-on-k8s-operator" from inside a different pod

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Following [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/docs/quick-start-guide.md#installation) guide, I have deployed a "spark-on-k8s" operator inside my Kubernetes cluster.

In the guide, it mentions how you can deploy Spark applications using kubectl commands.

My question is whether it is possible to deploy Spark applications from inside a different pod instead of kubectl commands?
Say, from some data pipeline applications such as Apache NiFi or Streamsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create pod from inside another pod.

All you need is to create a *ServiceAcount* with appropriate *Role* that will allow creating pods and assign it to the pod so then you can authenticate to kubernetes api server using rest api or one of k8s client libraries to create you pod.

Read more how to do it using [kubernetes api](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/)
in kubernetes documentation.

Also read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) on how to create roles.

And take a look [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) for list of k8s client libraries.

Let me know if it was helpful.

Comment: Thank you. Got it to work with the following command:

`curl --cacert "${CACERT}" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json, */*" PUT -d "$(cat spark-job.json)"  "${APISERVER}/apis/sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2/namespaces/$NAMESPACE/sparkapplications/"`

Comment: @toerq Could you point me to some references to the above REST end point? I have an exact similar requirement as such.

Comment: never mind, I got it https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/#-strong-api-overview-strong-